# How to share site title and some settings variable only with certain controller namespace in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have an admin section which is located at
app.dev/admin

I want to share site title and some settings like cache version to all the views that comes under this namespace.How do I do it?
I read this http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views#sharing-data-with-all-views but I only want to share data under the admin namespace. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an abstract controller on that namespace and make all other controllers from the same namespace to extend the abstract controller.

In the constructor on the abstract controller you can use this code to share the variables

```
view()->share([
    'version'  => $foo,
    'settings' => $bar,
]);
```

If you are not happy using the constructor you can also use any other method on the abstract controller and make sure you call that method on the child controller right before loading the views.

Another approach would be to create a trait with the method and make sure all the controllers on the namespace use the trait.

Comment: My app is almost finished! Is there any other way? I have about 30 controllers under the admin and it takes a lot time to change all that.

Comment: Replacing 30 lines is not that hard. Use the "search and replace" function of your IDE or one simple command such `cd My\Namesapce && sed -i '.bak' 's/extends OldController/extends NewController/g' *Controller.php`